# Are questions about clarifying the meaning of medication leaflets on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Today, we got a question which received a downvote and a close vote:

[Do dosage directions refer to the amount of medical product or to the amount of active ingredient of it?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4311/do-dosage-directions-refer-to-the-amount-of-medical-product-or-to-the-amount-of)

I must admit that I had to edit it, as the original version was slightly misleading. But in a nutshell, the user read a medication leaflet and found the information in it ambiguous. He posted here asking which of the possible interpretations is the correct one.

Is this question on topic? Is there a reason that wouldn't be in our scope?

Answer (score 4):

I went back and forth personally on this, as to whether it was on topic or not. The original post certainly did lean towards the "how much should *I* take" unless you read carefully, the edit makes it better.

In the end, I let it stand to see what the community thought of it. 4+ and -1 so far, which indicates an approval of the question. And, knowing HOW to read a leaflet like that certainly impacts health, and isn't specific to one person.

It might make a good community wiki type question, but so far it seems to be accepted as it stands.